# Why does browserify in 2 separate bundles not load the dependencies?

Tags: browserify

I am trying to separate my browserify vendor libs from my own code. I ran the following (simplified):

`browserify -r angular -o app/dist/vendor.js
browserify -x angular app/js/main.js -o app/dist/app.js`

When I load my app, I get `Error: Cannot find module 'angular'`.

If I run it all bundled as `browserify app/js/main.js -o app/dist/app.js` everything works fine. My main.js is rather simple, just looks like:

`var angular = require('angular'), app = require('./app');
angular.bootstrap(document,[app.name]);`

It is the first line, `require('angular')` that it stumbles upon.

Yes, I did set up a simple shim for angular along with a `browser` entry in package.json mapping it to my angular shim path, so that it works correctly (or it would not have worked in the all-in-one case).

I also tried manually editing the vendor.js and app.js with some logs to see when how they run. It looks like the wrapper function (yes, IIFE) for the app.js runs first, followed by the wrapper for vendor.js. And, I verified multiple times that the script tag for vendor.js is first, followed by the tag for app.js.

Could i have something to do with the fact that vendor.js is so much bigger (1.5 orders of magnitude) than app.js, and so app.js finishes loading first? I doubt it, or every ordered script tag for jquery or angular would break, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. Turns out the 2 tags were auto-generated. This causes them to be async and the browser is free to do what it wants with them in terms of completion order.

Comment: can you provide more info? I'm seeing a similar issue and am stumped. What do you mean by "the 2 tags were auto-generated" and how did you solve this issue?

Comment: Now I remember. If you place `<script>` tags in the page, the browser will load them in order. But if you have a JS (via a loader or other process) generate them, then the browser is free to load them in whatever order it wants. Thus, you can have app.js with `require('angular')` in it run before vendor.js, leading to the error. In my case, the `<script>` tags were being auto-generated.

Comment: aha! now I see it. Because you had two separately browserified script tags, they came in out of order. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much. The script tags were generated in order, but because the script tags were generated by JS, the browser loaded them how it saw fit. Since vendor.js was longer, it was finished loading and parsing later. requirejs does a good job managing this kind of thing, but browserify is so I could get away from requirejs...

Comment: Did it help with your problem?

Comment: sadly no, but I'm still glad to be able to cross one possible hangup off my list. There are a great many search results for "browserify cannot find module"; hopefully my answer is in here somewhere.

Comment: Post it as a new question, included all of your config, see what you get. Also, put a link to it here. I wrangled with enough browserify pain that happy to look at it too.

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't come to that, but [here we go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147775/browserify-require-in-required-file-cannot-find-module). Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.