# browserify require in required file cannot find module

Tags: browserify, browserify-shim

I'm trying to package my angular js into a single script using browserify. It works well when I use `require` from within my main file `app.js`, but when one of the modules required in `app.js` contains it's own `require`, the dependency is not included in my bundle.

To recap, in [`app.js` (link to line in repo)](https://github.com/7yl4r/ng-boot-boiler/blob/browserifyExample/app.js#L10):

```
require("splash-header");
// more code here
```

[splashHeader.js](https://github.com/7yl4r/ng-boot-boiler/blob/browserifyExample/ng-modules/splashHeader/splashHeader.js#L5):

```
require("social-button-directive");
// more code here
```

[socialButtons.js](https://github.com/7yl4r/ng-boot-boiler/blob/browserifyExample/ng-modules/socialButtons/socialButtons.js) has no dependencies.

`browserify --list app.js` does not list `splashHeader.js` as it should, and the bundle produced via `browserify app.js -o bundle.js` does not include socialButton's javascript. So of course if I attempt to load the site anyway, I get `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'social-button-directive'` at splashHeader's `require('social-button-directive')`.

Also important to note that I'm mapping module names to file locations using the "browser" option in `package.json`, and using browerify-shim since none of my modules are common-js compatible.

relevant section of [package.json](https://github.com/7yl4r/ng-boot-boiler/blob/browserifyExample/package.json#L26-L68):

```
"dependencies": {
    "browserify": "~9.0.3",
    "browserify-shim": "~3.8.3"
},
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
        "browserify-shim"
    ]
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "splash-header": {
        "depends": "angular",
        "exports": "angular.module('splash-header').name"
    },
    "social-button-directive": {
        "depends": "angular",
        "exports": "angular.module('social-button-directive').name"
    }
},
"browser":{
    "splash-header": "./ng-modules/splashHeader/splashHeader.js",
    "social-button-directive": "./ng-modules/socialButtons/socialButtons.js"
}
```

I've been on this all morning and am completely stumped. I've cut down the offending project to serve as [a minimal example of the issue](https://github.com/7yl4r/ng-boot-boiler/tree/browserifyExample). To test things out just clone and npm install. If you're looking in detail, here's the [working/not working version diff](https://github.com/7yl4r/ng-boot-boiler/commit/4f1f991fe873d5ea64bdae1c70bf3eab854b28d3).

I've tried loading the submodule by relative path (`require('./ng-modules/socialButtons/socialButtons.js`)`), no luck. Perhaps I have shimmed things incorrectly? My approach on this comes from [this article](http://aymericbeaumet.me/properly-shim-angularjs-applications-using-browserify/).

*EDIT*: It is most certainly my browserify-shim configuration. Everything works after converting the modules to commonjs and removing the browserfy-shim options from package.json. I guess I just had to write this all out to pin it down. =/

Comment: This is a strange question, but why do you have `require('ngTouch')` and similar inside the `angular.module('ng-boot-boiler-demo',[...])` array? Should those not be strings that represent the registered module names? `require(...)` should be at the top?

Comment: It's definitely a strange arrangement. Check out the article linked at the bottom of my post for more info. I liked the approach because it reduces repetition of the string.

Comment: Just checked it out. How odd. I mean, maybe angular supports that, but I have never seen it. To some extent, repetition is unavoidable. `require()` is for loading, and `[]` is for the angular dependency tree. Much of that is eliminated with angular 2.0 and ES6 modules, but that is in the future. Either way, can you try it without that weird structure and see?

Comment: It looks like my issue was primarily with usage of browserfy-shim, so I'm going to convert my modules to commonjs and move on. I believe I did try what you are suggesting earlier this morning however, and it did not resolve my issue.

Comment: Oh, shim. That reminds me of something....

Comment: Yeah, there was some weird bug where browserify-shim would fail on things installed via npm? I wish I could remember it...

Comment: Oh, yeah. Look at this. Is it relevant? https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/975

Comment: possibly, I'm new to both angular and browserify so I'm not sure. I'm just happy to have a workaround so I can start debugging something less pedantic.

Comment: That is the problem with these tools. Once you get them working how you want, they really are great. But until you do... bogged down in the weeds! Glad it worked out.